# How to find unresolved files using the Perforce p4java library?

Tags: java, perforce, p4java

Using the p4java library from Perforce (http://kb.perforce.com/article/1086/p4java-api), I'm trying to find out what files in a changelist are unresolved and need to be resolved before I can submit them.

```
IChangelist changelist = getServer().getChangelist(changelistId);
List<IFileSpec> changelistPendingFiles = changelist.getFiles(false);
```

In this List, I'm trying to figure out which IFileSpec still need to be resolved.

Something like this:

```
for (IFileSpec pendingFile : changelistPendingFiles) {
    // How to find out if pendingFile needs to be resolved?

    FileAction action = pendingFile.getAction();
    // The above results in "FileAction.EDIT",
    // but that doesn't tell me anything about the unresolved state

    // The "diffStatus" variable for this pendingFile is "pending"
    // The "howResolved" variable for this pendingFile is null
    // The "opStatus" variable for this pendingFile is VALID
}
```

Thanks for anything you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comprehensive way is to run P4Java's version of the *fstat* command, and check if the file needs resolving.  Here's a code sample (not guaranteed to be bulletproof) that works in a simple test case.

```
List<IExtendedFileSpec> extfiles = server.getExtendedFiles(changelistPendingFiles,
    -1,
    -1,
    -1,
    new FileStatOutputOptions(false, false, false, false, false, true),
    null);

for(IExtendedFileSpec extfile : extfiles) {        
    System.out.println(extfile.isUnresolved());
}
```

In the *FileStatOutputOptions*, I'm asking for information on files that are open and need resolving.  The *isUnresolved* method should tell you what you want.

Hope that helps!